# how to uninstall Angular cli 6.0.8

Tags: uninstall

how to uninstall angular cli completely? i had installed node then Angular cli. I uninstalled node and installed another version but angular cli is not removed and remain same.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Angular Cli globally then just deinstall it with `npm uninstall -g <angular cli version>`

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:-

`sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` or `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

npm cache clean

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` or `npm install -g @angular/cli`

**Note : On Windows run this using administrator and on Mac use sudo**

You can also go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566257/how-to-uninstall-angular-cli) if above step didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

Try the Following steps to uninstall angular cli completely

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli // Use sudo before to give administrator permission
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli // Use sudo before to give administrator permission
```

`npm cache clean` or `npm cache clean --force`

To reinstall the latest version try this

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall angular completely use following commands,

I. If you want to remove global angular-cli :

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@<version>
```

For example,

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@6.0.8
```

II. In case other cases

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli
```